# Jquery mask plugin working sometimes on rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, view, mask

I'm trying to use mask on my form. So:
My application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require select2
//= require masks
```

My masks.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cep').mask('99999-999');
   $('#phone').mask('(99) 99999-9999');
   $('#second_phone').mask('(99) 99999-9999');
});
```

My view:

```
.col-lg-6
  .form-group
    = f.input :telefone, :input_html => { :class => 'form-control', |
                                          :id => 'phone' }
```

The plugin reference https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin.

What is wrong?

Comment: How is the plugin loaded?

Comment: It was downloaded and added to /assets/javascripts/ directory

Comment: To rule out turbolinks can you try the [`jquery-turbolinks`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed `//= require turbolinks` from `application.js` and worked fine.

Comment: I don't suggest that. Might breake something else.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, better than disabling turbolinks would be opt-out, you can do it but adding the attribute "data-no-turbolink" to any HTML element that you need the target to

Complete documentation:

https://github.com/sstephenson/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md